# PHP ftp_connect doesn't responds from batch file in scheduled task

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, ftp, scheduled-tasks

I have a **PHP script** that synchronize a local directory with a remote one ...

```
[...]
$ftp = new Ftp('11.222.11.222', 'the_user', 'the_pass');
$ftp->syncFolder('userfiles/project', '/web/userfiles/project', true);
[...]
```

And a Class

```
class Ftp
{
    public $conn;
    private $url;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $loged;


    /**
     * Ftp constructor.
     * @param $url
     * @param $user
     * @param $password
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function __construct($url, $user, $password)
    {

        $this->conn = ftp_connect($url);
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;


        if ($this->ftp_login($this->user, $this->password)) {

            $this->loged = true;
        } else {

            $this->loged = false;
        }

        $this->ftp_pasv(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param $func
     * @param $a
     * @return mixed
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function __call($func, $a)
    {
        if (strstr($func, 'ftp_') !== false && function_exists($func)) {
            array_unshift($a, $this->conn);
            return call_user_func_array($func, $a);
        } else {
            if (method_exists($this, $func)) {
                return call_user_func_array($func, $a);
            } else {
                throw new Exception('Undefine Class Function');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $local
     * @param $server
     * @param $verbose
     * @return bool
     * @throws Exception
     */
    function syncFolder($local, $server, $verbose)
    {
        if (!$this->loged) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->ftp_chdir($server);
        $server_list = $this->ftp_nlist('.');
        $local_list = scandir(BASE_PATH . $local);

        foreach ($server_list as $item) {
            if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') {
                continue;
            }

            $folder = $this->ftp_nlist($item);

            if ($folder[0] == '.') {
                if (!in_array($item, $local_list)) {
                    $this->emptyDir($server . '/' . $item, $verbose);
                    $this->ftp_chdir($server);
                } else {
                    $this->syncFolder($local . '/' . $item, $server . '/' . $item, $verbose);
                    $this->ftp_chdir($server);
                }
            } else {
                if (!in_array($item, $local_list)) {
                    if ($this->ftp_delete($item)) {

                    } else {

                    }
                } else {
                    $stats = stat(BASE_PATH . $local . '/' . $item);

                    if ($this->ftp_mdtm($item) < $stats['mtime']) {
                        if ($this->ftp_put($item, BASE_PATH . $local . '/' . $item, FTP_BINARY)) {

                        } else {

                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                }
            }

        }

        $this->putMissingFilesFromDir($local, $server, $verbose);
        $this->ftp_chdir($server);
    }


    /**
     * @param $dir
     * @param $verbose
     * @return bool
     * @throws Exception
     */
    function emptyDir($dir, $verbose)
    {
        if (!$this->loged) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->ftp_chdir($dir);
        $server_list = $this->ftp_nlist('.');

        foreach ($server_list as $item) {
            if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') {
                continue;
            }
            $folder = $this->ftp_nlist($item);
            if ($folder[0] == '.') {
                $this->emptyDir($dir . '/' . $item, $verbose);
                $this->ftp_chdir($dir);
            } else {
                if ($this->ftp_delete($item)) {

                } else {

                }
            }
        }

        if ($this->ftp_rmdir($dir)) {

        } else {

        }
    }


    /**
     * @param $local
     * @param $server
     * @param $verbose
     * @return bool
     * @throws Exception
     */
    function putMissingFilesFromDir($local, $server, $verbose)
    {
        if (!$this->loged) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->ftp_chdir($server);
        $server_list = $this->ftp_nlist('.');
        $local_list = scandir(BASE_PATH . $local);

        foreach ($local_list as $item) {
            if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') {
                continue;
            }
            if (is_dir(BASE_PATH . $local . '/' . $item)) {
                if (!in_array($item, $server_list)) {
                    $this->ftp_mkdir($item);
                }
                $this->putMissingFilesFromDir($local . '/' . $item, $server . '/' . $item, $verbose);
                $this->ftp_chdir($server);

            } else {
                if (!in_array($item, $server_list)) {
                    if ($this->ftp_put($item, BASE_PATH . $local . '/' . $item, FTP_BINARY)) {

                    } else {

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

This script **works fine from browser and from windows' CMD** using this command:

```
C:\php5.6\php.exe -f "D:\www\project\cron\synchro_hosting.php"
```

But when I try to run this script **from a batch** file in a scheduled task the ftp_connect function **doesn't do anything**. It remains waiting for something.

```
cd /D "D:\www\project\cron\"
"C:\php5.6\php.exe" -f synchro_hosting.php
```

I'm using a log file to write events (now removed for summarize the code) and the code stop in ftp_connect.

Ideas?

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried to run the same command from CMD, batch file triggered from CMD and a batch file triggered from scheduled task, and works fine with two first options. The execution stops in ftp_connect function when is triggered from batch file in a scheduled task. The windows user that execute this actions is the same in the three cases.

```
C:\php5.6\php.exe -f "D:\www\project\cron\synchro_hosting.php"
```

I don't know where is the problem with ftp_connect from scheduled task. Is maybe a permissions issue?

There are another way in Windows to trigger an php script recurrently?

Comment: Is your PHP file in the directory you are changing to?  Is the D: drive a local drive or a mapped network drive?

Comment: I'm not sure why your batch file doesn't just contain the same command you used at the `cmd.exe` prompt. If you're specifically wanting to stipulate the working directory, you could also consider using the `Start` command with its `/D` option. Given the information you've provided, there's nothing wrong with the batch file. It is however undetermined what the working directory was in your 'working' CMD example.

Comment: @Squashman: My php file and my batch file are in the same directori `www\project\cron\synchro_hosting.php` and `www\project\cron\cron.bat`. D: drive is a local drive.

Comment: @Compo : OK, this monday I will try your suggestions

Comment: @Compo ... it still doesn't work

Comment: @Aston I have the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: @Rocstar, I have found a solution to avoid the problem, not to fix it. I tried to execute a php file directly from scheduled tasks and it worked. I will post the concrete solution later to help users in with the same trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I told to Rockstar, I have found a solution to avoid the problem, not to fix it. I tried to execute a php file directly from scheduled tasks and it worked instead of execute a bat file.

The action tab from scheduled tasks should look like this:

**Action**: Start a program
**Program or Script**: C:\php5.6\php.exe
**Add arguments**: "D:\www\project\cron\synchro_hosting.php"

[Action Tab from Scheduled Tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtOSu.png)